# TPL .Net Concurrenty Issue with Azure EventHub Producer

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, azure-eventhub

I am working with Azure Event Hub producer client and reading messages off of a kafka stream then pass it along to deserialize/map, then pass to Event Hub.  I have the consume loop which is creating a task for each consume and then two methods to do processing(this seems to have greatly improved the speed from the kafka lag perspective.  However, Event hub makes you create an event batch which I don't necessarily want to use.  I just want to send the data one message at a time for now.  In order to create a new batch I have to call Dispose().  I am running into an issue where there's another call to the function by the the time I call Dispose() and I get an error saying the object is being used by event hub.

I've also tried using the overload for eventHubProducerClient.SendAsync that allows you to pass in a IEnumerable but i'm running into the same issue with that.

So I believe this to be a synchronization issue, or maybe I need to do a lock somewhere?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
       public void Execute()
                {
                    using (_consumer)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _consumer.Subscribe(_streamConsumerSettings.Topic);
                            while (true)
                            {
                                var result = _consumer.Consume(1000);
        
                                if (result == null)
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                var process = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessMessage(result?.Message?.Value));
                                var send = process.ContinueWith(t => SendMessage(process.Result));                        
                            }
        
                        }
                        catch (ConsumeException e)
                        {
                            _logger.LogError(e, e.StackTrace ?? e.Message);
                            _cancelConsume = true;
                            _consumer.Close();
                            RestartConsumer();
                        }
                    }
                }
    
         public static EquipmentJson ProcessMessage(byte[] result)
         {
                    var json = _messageProcessor.DeserializeAndMap(result);
                    return json;
         }
        
         public static void SendMessage(EquipmentJson message)
         {
                    try 
                    {   
        
                        _eventHubClient.AddToBatch(message);             
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(e, e.StackTrace ?? e.Message);
                    }
          }
    
     
    
        public async Task AddToBatch(EquipmentJson message)
                {
                    if 
      (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.EquipmentLocation))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var batch = await _equipmentLocClient.CreateBatchAsync();
                            batch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.EquipmentLocation)));
                            await _eventHubProducerClient.SendAsync(batch);
                            batch.Dispose();
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Data sent {DateTimeOffset.UtcNow}");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            _logger.LogError(e, e.StackTrace ?? e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }

 public class EventHubClient : IEventHubClient
    {
        private readonly ILoggerAdapter<EventHubClient> _logger;
        private readonly EventHubClientSettings _eventHubClientSettings;
        private IMapper _mapper;

        
        private static EventHubProducerClient _equipmentLocClient;


        public EventHubClient(ILoggerAdapter<EventHubClient> logger, EventHubClientSettings eventHubClientSettings, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _eventHubClientSettings = eventHubClientSettings;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _equipmentLocClient = new EventHubProducerClient(_eventHubClientSettings.ConnectionString, _eventHubClientSettings.EquipmentLocation);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me understand which Event Hubs client library you're using and include the client creation in your snippet?

Comment: I'm using the latest library from the MSFT quickstart.  Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;  Updated the post above with the client creation.  I'm registering the EventHubClient class as a singleton which is probably my problem.  Since I'm hitting that class multiple times in different tasks.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The event batch is currently being used in communication with the Event Hubs service; events may not be added until the active operation is complete.
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventDataBatch.AssertNotLocked()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventDataBatch.TryAdd(EventData eventData)

Comment: That is interesting.   I don't spot anything obvious; your use of the client and the flow of your send is perfectly fine.  The client is safe to use concurrently and as a long-lived object and each send operation is independent.  Multiple calls to Send can be active at the same time with no sync needed.

That stack trace indicates that something is trying to modify the batch while a send operation is taking place.  I can't reproduce the behavior in a console application using snippets of your code.

Comment: The only speculation that I can offer at the moment is that it appears that something in your flow is running the two awaited calls back-to-back without yielding to the TryAdd.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my speculation in comments, I'm curious if refactoring to use `async/await` rather than the explicit continuation in the main loop may help.  Perhaps something similar to the following LinqPad snippet:

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var message = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetText());
        var events = new[] { new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)) };
        
        await Send(events).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public EventHubProducerClient client = new EventHubProducerClient("<< CONNECTION STRING >>");

public async Task Send(EventData[] events)
{
    try
    {
        await client.SendAsync(events).ConfigureAwait(false);
        "Sent".Dump();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Dump();
    }
}

public string GetText()
{
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    return "Test";
}
```

If you're set on keeping the continuation, I wonder if a slight structural refactoring in the continuation may help, both to push up creation of the events and to honor the `await` statements.  Perhaps something similar to the following LinqPad snippet:

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetText());
        var _ = t.ContinueWith(async q =>
        {
            var events = new[] { new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(t.Result)) };
            await Send(events).ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
        
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}

public EventHubProducerClient client = new EventHubProducerClient("<< CONNECTION STRING >>");

public async Task Send(EventData[] events)
{
    try
    {
        await client.SendAsync(events).ConfigureAwait(false);
        "Sent".Dump();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Dump();
    }
}

public string GetText()
{
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    return "Test";
}
```

Comment: I'll take a look at your suggestion and let you know.  Thanks!